# Split and parse window.location.hash

Tags: javascript

I'm facing issues with splitting and parsing `window.location.hash` correctly.

First of all, we get few parameters in hash, ex:

```
#loc=austria&mr=1&min=10&max=89
```

As you surely see it's been created for search. When user clicks on pagination link page is being reloaded with the hash. So far so good.

I created function initialise() that is calling every time when there's hash in the URL:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var params = (window.location.hash.substr(1)).split("&");

    for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
    {
        var a = params[i].split("=");
        // Now every parameter from the hash is beind handled this way
        if (a[0] == "loc")
        {
            locationList(a[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Everythig is almost working... When I choose all search params hash is being... cut. For unknown reason for me. I tried to use `if( params.indexOf('loc') )` instead of `a[0] == "loc"` without any luck.

Could you lend me a hand?

**Edit**
Of course, I was using var a = ... in the loop, it was only copy-paste error.

Comment: *When I choose all search params hash is being... cut.* I don't understand this sentence...

Comment: When I have hash like this `#loc=austria&mr=1&min=10&max=89` after page reload it's `#loc=austria&mr=1`.

Comment: Have you tried `if( params[i].indexOf('loc') )` ??

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need a loop, if it's only the value of `loc` from the hash you're after. This should also work.

```
var lochash    = location.hash.substr(1),
    mylocation = lochash.substr(lochash.search(/(?<=^|&)loc=/))
                  .split('&')[0]
                  .split('=')[1];
if (mylocation) {
   locationList(myLocation);
}
```

Concerning the trunctating of the hash after a page reload: imho that isn't related to your loop.

**Edit** A more modern and more accurate approach:

```js
const result = document.querySelector("#result");
const hash2Obj = "loc=austria&mr=1&test123=test=123&min=10&max=89"
      .split("&")
      .map(v => v.split(`=`, 1).concat(v.split(`=`).slice(1).join(`=`)) )
      .reduce( (pre, [key, value]) => ({ ...pre, [key]: value }), {} );
          
result.textContent += `loc => ${hash2Obj.loc}
----
*hash2Obj (stringified):
${JSON.stringify(hash2Obj, null, ' ')}`;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: You are right. Now I realised that I have a logical error (calling buildRequestHash() function even if the hash exist). Thanks.

Comment: Technically, you have a minor bug if '=' is used unescaped in a value string ... think about the case "#key1=foo=bar,alloc=true&loc=...".  Not a huge deal, just something I bumped into.  Cheers!

Comment: Also matches `#bloc=thing`

Comment: @Hugo: you're right. The 'more modern approach' doesn't

Comment: Be careful with the `/(?<=^|&)loc=/` RegEx, it failed me on firefox and Safari.

Comment: To handle the problem reported by @DaveDopson you may replace `.map(v => v.split("="))` by `.map(v => { const id = v.indexOf('='); return id>-1?[v.slice(0,id),v.slice(id+1)]:[v,true];})`

Answer (score 20):

This should be a rather simpler way to read from location.hash:

```
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var params = {}
    hash.split('&').map(hk => { 
      let temp = hk.split('='); 
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1] 
    });
    console.log(params); //Here are the params to use
```

and then, you could use

```
params.access_token //access_token 
params.id //id
```

and other params that are available inside the hash

Answer (score 0):

`params.indexOf('loc')` will not return a value as `loc` does not exist within the `params` array. The item that you are looking for in the example provided is `loc=austria`. If you are only selecting by the key then you would need some looping to examine each key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing the hash, you may have to handle unescaped **=** characters. In this case, the use of **split** is not recommended. In addition, you could also handle empty hash, empty values (ususally interpreted as true) and use **decodeURIComponent** for encoded values.

```
const hash2Obj = function (hash) {
  // remove first char if necessary
  hash = (hash && (hash.charAt(0) === '#' || hash.charAt(0) === '?') ? hash.slice(1) : hash);
  // return empty object if empty
  if (!hash) return {};
  const obj = {};
  hash
  .split("&")
  .forEach(v => {
    // seek only first '=' char
    const id = v.indexOf('=');
    const [key, value] = id > -1 ? [v.slice(0, id), decodeURIComponent(v.slice(id + 1))]
    // handle absence of value as true
    : [v, true];
    if (key in obj) {
      // repeating values are usually intepreted as array
      if (!(obj[key] instanceof Array)) obj[key] = [obj[key]];
      obj[key].push(value);
    } else {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return obj;
};

const getSearch = function () {
  return hash2Obj(window.location.search);
};
const getHash = function () {
  return hash2Obj(window.location.hash);
};
```