# Save (cache?) some values of the page for future reloads

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have an `input` in my webpage. When a use enters a value, I want to keep the value for the future reloads of the page. Like if the use enters a value in the `input` and closes the page, I want to load the value, next time that the user loads the page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [Web Storage API](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). If you want to support <IE8, check out [this](http://github.com/wojodesign/local-storage-js). Although not recommended for security reasons, you can also use [cookies](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). Finally, if your data is not sensitive, you could store information in the url using [`location.hash`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5646851/2006429) or [`location.query`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/2006429) and parsing data from it.

Comment: @usandfriends could you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes, but as a note, my comment does not go over React implementation of these APIs. See @Michael's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31518822/2006429) for that information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
    mixins : [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState : function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('savedText')) {
            return (
                {savedText : localStorage.getItem('savedText')}
            );
        } else {
            return (
                {savedText : ''}
            );
        }
    },
    componentDidUpdate : function () {
        localStorage.setItem('savedText', this.state.savedText);
    },
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                Enter some text, then refresh the page
                <br/>
                <input type='text' valueLink={this.linkState('savedText')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Explanation:

- `getInitialState` is used to check if the saved value in localStorage exists.  If it does, it sets our `savedText` state to whatever the value is - if it does not, it sets the state to an empty string.
- The `LinkedStateMixin` ensures that the `savedText` state is always equivalent to the value in the input.  Thus, `getInitialState` is actually setting the initial value of the input, and every time the input value changes, the state changes along with it.
- Every time a state change is made (so every time the value in the input changes), `componentDidUpdate` is called, which stores the current value back into localStorage.

I opted to use localStorage, which will save the value even if the browser closes, but if you are just interested in keeping the value after a page refresh, then sessionStorage will work just fine too.

Here is a demo of it working: http://output.jsbin.com/bayayikipi