# OAuth2: Extract access_token fragment from implicit flow

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I don't quite figure out how to handle oauth2 implicit flow response. I've created a SPA using angular4. As far I've been able to get I need to create a request looks like:

```
GET /authorize?
  response_type=token&
  client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&
  state=xyz&
  redirect_uri=<<uri-located-into-SPA>>
```

What I don't quite to get is how to handle with the response. The response is a redirection to previously specified `redirect_uri` query parameter.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: <<uri-located-into-SPA>>#access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA&
    state=xyz&
    token_type=example&
    expires_in=3600
```

So, how should I implement the `<<uri-located-into-SPA>>` in order to extract the `access_token` and which <> should I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect URI (for example `/auth/oauth2`) should be mapped to a component that will [parse the hash part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647103/731178) of the current browser URL, save the `access_token` value somewhere (sessionStorage, localStorage or some some Angular service or store). If you want to send the access token along with each backend request, create an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) (from the new Angular HttpClient API) that adds it there.

If you want to refresh the access token before it expires, you should also set a timeout function for refreshing the access token (using a hidden `iframe` and `prompt=none` URL parameter).

The component doesn't need to have any real view. When the processing is finished, just change the route to some existing application component - an initial view or a view that was requested before the authentication.

Comment: I've just created a component without specifying a template and I'm getting this error: `No template specified for component DBoxOAuthComponent`. Is it possible to create a component without a template?

Comment: Probably you cannot do it, but you can create an empty template or one with a simple content such as "Please wait ..." text.

Comment: I don't quite figure out how to build an url in order to test my component. I mean, all routes have a `#` symbol like that `localhost:3002/#/{login|app...}`. I've never figured out why this `#` appears. However, now I need to put an `access_token` fragment into the url in order to test component. I've tried `localhost:3002/#/oauth#access_token=234` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the redirect URL should not contain hash part (#...). By default Angular uses HTML5 routing without the hash, but can be configured to use it by `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`. So try to find it in your project and if possible, change it to `false`. For more info, see https://angular.io/guide/router#browser-url-styles

Comment: I've removed `useHash` and now angular is applying `PathLocationStrategy` calss. I'm facing now with a strange routing behavior. I mean, When I'm trying to go to `localhost:3002\oauth` location, the location path changes to `localhost:3002\oauth\login` (`login` is the root application path). I've also tried to go to `localhost:3002\login`, however location path changes to `localhost:3002\login\login`... Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot tell by the description, but you could try to debug it - check whether the new component gets executed. And you will probably need to configure your web server to serve index.html for all URLs under the root path of your application.

Comment: Could you provide me any stuff helping code for configuring my webserver. In production I'm using nginx, and in development webpack-dev-server.