# How do you read a hash with an "&" sign in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, fragment-identifier

I am building a dynamic website using jQuery and Ajax. I want to read the `id` after the hash in the following URL:

```
something.php#type=abc&id=123
```

My current code to read hash value is:

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
alert(hash);
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646851/split-and-parse-window-location-hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(hash);
if(searchParams.has('id')) {
  var id = searchParams.get('id');
  console.log(id);
}
```

And same for other params if any. Hope this helps.

Comment: But var hash gets abc&id=123 :/ It should get oinly Hashtag

Comment: @CalvinKlein I didn't get you. If you want to get the value of type, you can just do `searchParams .get('type')`.

Comment: I want to get the value of Hashtag without id